# Do we need to use different grpc connections for different streams for same client (specific to golang)?

Tags: go, stream, grpc, grpc-go

My project (in golang) has a use case where I need to open several streams from single GRPC client to single/multiple GRPC servers.

Say my proto file is -

```
syntax = "proto3";
package helloworld;

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (stream HelloRequest) returns (stream HelloReply) {}
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

Now for my client I have 2 options -

```
package main

import (
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "hello/grpc/helloworld"
)

func newConn() helloworld.GreeterClient {
    conn, err := grpc.Dial("localhost:9009", grpc.WithInsecure())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return helloworld.NewGreeterClient(conn)
}

func clientWork(client helloworld.GreeterClient) {
    // client work
}

func main() {
    // option 1 - new connection objects for all streams
    for i:=0; i<1000; i++ {
        clientWork(newConn())
    }
    
    // option 2 - single connection object for all streams
    globalConn := newConn()
    for i:=0; i<1000; i++ {
        clientWork(globalConn)
    }
}
```

Option 1 is using new **grpc.Conn** for streams

Option 2 is using single global **grpc.Conn** for all streams

My question - is their any recommended way of achieving the same (if it is case specific, can I get some exmaples)

I went through https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/2086#issuecomment-389947160 that suggests that to release underlying buffers/memory I have few options one of which includes closing the grpc.Conn that got me thinking which option should be more suitable in my case.

Thanks

Comment: fwiw, I've been using a single grpc connection with both streams and regular calls and have not observed a problem.

Comment: @BurakSerdar ever encountered issues like https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/3728 ? I am observing similar issues

Comment: I haven't observed this so far.

Answer (score 1):

With gRPC it is generally recommended that you use a single connection for all streams to the same server. The main exceptions are for servers that have limits on the number of concurrent streams per connection.

Comment: followup question on that, if same connection is being used, how do we clear buffer for streams that are no longer in use? If I use different connection object, I can simply close them and it will release any held memory for the stream.

Comment: I think that you can cancel the context used to create the stream, and that cascades through the stack and cleans up the stream. See the docs for NewStream: https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#ClientConn.NewStream